# Galois VS Fibonacci LFSR, more computer-friendly but what else?

Tags: algorithm, math

According the [Linear feedback shift register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) page on Wikipedia,

Beside that the Galois LFSR is more computer-friendly,
can you tell what are the real advantages of using a Galois one over a Fibonacci one ?

In other words, I am already satisfied with the results of the Fibonacci LFSR but in what the Galois one can be even better ?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output sequences are exactly the same (for a given polynomial).  The only difference is the implementation.  If you are implementing a LFSR in a CPU then the Galois structure is likely faster.  If you are implementing it in an FPGA it may not matter.

Answer (score 12):

If you are implementing it in an FPGA it *does* matter. The maximum clocking frequency of the shift register is determined strongly by the maximum propagation delay of the circuit. Fibonacci LFSRs have to XOR several bits together requiring either cascaded 2-input XOR gates or multiple-input XOR gates, whereas Galois LFSRs use 2-input XOR gates, so their propagation delay is minimized, and can run at a faster frequency.

If you are using multiple bits at once, Fibonacci LFSRs have the advantage that the next N bits are immediately visible in the shift register, because all the shift register stages (except for the first one) get their input only from the previous stage.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. (I wanted to mark your reply as an answer as well but I could only mark one; it's been very helpful as well !)

Comment: I agree that it does potentially matter. However, I think there are still important cases where Fibonacci LFSRs are actually better for both area and timing performance (in FPGA or ASIC). For example, 2-tap LFSRs (which are very widely used because they are cheap) need two 2-input XORs for Galois, but only one 2-input XOR for Fibonacci.

Answer (score 3):

I have to disagree with Jason. Modern FPGAs use LUTs that typically support 6 input logic functions. Therefore whether you need a 2-input XOR for Galois or a 3 or 4 input XOR for Fibonacci, you need a single LUT and the delay will be the same. Even in an ASIC where you will actually get a difference in logic gates, the small geometries now being used are more affected by interconnect delay than gate delay. Unless you are trying to squeeze every picosecond out of your design, there shouldn't be a noticeable difference between these two implementations. If using an FPGA I suspect you will see no difference.

Comment: talking of picoseconds... in some FPGAs the inputs to the LUTs have different delays (at the picosecond level IIRC), so limiting to 2 inputs *can* still help